# Model State not checked in MVC WebAPI when called from Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following class defintion in my WebAPI:

```
public class LogIt
    {
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Log ID required")]
        public int LogID { get; set; }
        public int StatusID { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
    }
```

When calling it with Restlet directly, it validated correctly and err's when LogID is not included in the JSON payload.

Here is a shell of what is called in the controller:

```
 public IHttpActionResult PostTrace([FromBody]LogIt log)
        {          
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                 LogIt.Insert(log);
            }
            return Ok();                                      
        }
```

From my client application, I have the following class defined:

```
public class LogIt
        {           
            public int LogID { get; set; }
            public int StatusID { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public int UserID { get; set; }
        }
```

And the code that calls:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/api/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

LogIt log = new LogIt();
log.StatusID = 1;
log.Message = "Test";
log.UserID = 1;

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("log/trace/insert", log);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

However, the LogID never gets checked in the WebAPI as a "Required" field, so modelstate is valid, and when the DB insert/update happens, I get an error (obviously)

Any idea why this is? Should I bring the attribute for required field into the client app as well?

Comment: It has a `LogID`, because the default value for an int is `0`. The json would look like `{ LogId: 0, /*etc.*/ }`. The validator probably checks if the source has `undefined` fields/properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `LogIt log = new LogIt();` in your client application, `LogID` will be set to 0 by the constructor. This **is** a value, so will be sent in your JSON payload as "logID: 0", for example.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the difference between payloads just now. I'm using [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.") instead of "Required" on the integer field now since the PostAsJsonAsync adds 0 as you explained. Thanks!